# Ember nested component action

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have looked through all the answers and google results I could find about it and all I got out of it is that it is quite a common problem. Unfortunately non helped me to solve my case.

I have this custom button:

```
App.ButtonCmpComponent = Ember.Component.extend({

    tagName: 'button',

    classNameBindings: ['btn', 'class'],
    btn: 'btn',
    class: 'btn-default',

    attributeBindings: ['type'],
    type: 'button',

    click : function () {
        this.sendAction();
    }
});
```

As well as a button group component:

```
App.ButtonGroupCmpComponent = Ember.Component.extend({

});
```

With this template:

```
{{#each btn in definition}}
    {{button-cmp action=btn.action}}
{{/each}}
```

In my index controller I have the following:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

    actions: {

        test : function () {
            alert('test in index controller')
        }
    }
});
```

And index view defined the content via a simple hash:

```
App.IndexView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'views/index',

    buttonGroup : [
        { label : "Test Action", action : 'test' },
        { label : 'Other Btn', action : 'test' }
    ]
});
```

And finally in index view:

```
{{button-cmp action="test"}}

{{btn-group-cmp definition=view.buttonGroup}}
```

My problem is that the first button defined directly on the view does trigger correct action in index controller but the two buttons inside button group controller do not. In fact I can't even identify the target where those actions are being sent to from within the nest component at all.

What am I doing wrong here? How can I define a nested button component in such a way that it would still send the action to the same index controller handler?

Thank you

**EDIT:**

By trial and error I have found how to direct the action to the correct controller. I don't think that I quite understand how it works though so **Please post an answer with the explanation of what really is going on here**... I'd really like to get my head around this eventually.

*This is how I made it to work:*

In index view I have added a `target=this` to the component invocation like this:

```
{{btn-group-cmp definition=view.buttonGroup target=this}}
```

And then, added `targetObject=view` to the nested component invocation as follows:

```
{{#each btn in definition}}
    {{button-cmp action=btn.action targteObject=view}}
{{/each}}
```

This resulted in actions defined in `view.buttonGroup` to be correctly sent to the view controller instead of some unknown to me location.